# Drop down consists of many items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am facing weird kinda situation. I have form which consists of 6 Fields among which 1 is drop down list. Now i have filled that drop down from another table but problem is that the Drop Down consists loads many items (ComplaintID) and can extent further. So what can be the solution instead of using Drop down or trimming it or anything.

Comment: You really should try and further filter that list.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried a listbox?  that lets you scroll so doesn't matter how many items really

Comment: actually i want to see whole record for confirmation

Comment: You could add columns to the ListBox [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn(v=vs.110).aspx
or you could use a DataGridView depending on what technology you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
- [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Also have a look at

[Why drop-down lists are bad for the user experience?](https://medium.com/design-ux/eeda5cbbd315)

[What are the alternatives to a very long dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436980/what-are-the-alternatives-to-a-very-long-dropdown)

[Alternatives to huge drop down lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400864/alternatives-to-huge-drop-down-lists-24-000-items)